# save objects in casdade (Save and/or Update) Entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I´m wondering if its possible to work with one object in Entity Framework and when I update the principal, EF creates or updates the lists, Let me show one example:

[Objects Relation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJ2FW.png) (image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJ2FW.png)

In this example, we have a Companie with a list of Employees with has a list of addresses and phones. If a create one Company, in disconnected mode. After that I will add some Employees with Addressees and Phones, It´s possible, like NHibernate, send this back to Context and the EF resolve what is update and what is created?

Like this?

```
using (var db = new CompanyContext())
{
  db.Companies.Attach(cia);
  db.Entry(cia).State = EntityState.Modified;
  db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In contrast to NHibernate, EF must be told what to update/create/delete explicitly in disconnected mode, as far as know. The good news is that there's a solution:

http://blog.brentmckendrick.com/introducing-graphdiff-for-entity-framework-code-first-allowing-automated-updates-of-a-graph-of-detached-entities/

I used it in one of my projects, worked a treat for me.